Nuxt & Supabase , update JSONB data
const programming_languages = ref<string>('');
const save = async () => {
  try {
    const updatedData = {
      programming_languages: programming_languages.value,
    };
    await updateProfile(updatedData);
 } catch (error) {
    toast.add({
      severity: 'error',
      summary: 'Error',
      detail: `Failed to save data${error instanceof Error ? `: ${error.message}` : ''}`,
      life: 3000,
    });
onMounted(async () => {
  programming_languages.value =
    (profile.value?.programming_languages as unknown as string[])?.join(', ') ??
    '';
});

<InputText
v-model="programming_languages"
></InputText>

please i have a vue component where i display a jsonb column from supabase and defined as array like this:
programming_languages: ["PHP", "JS", "Python"], so i fetched the profile data correctly but on save i cannot update the jsonb data i get this response on save:
{
    "code": "22P02",
    "details": "Array value must start with \"{\" or dimension information.",
    "hint": null,
    "message": "malformed array literal: \"\""
}

what can i do to ensure updating this field?

If it's expected to be an array and you're providing a string, that's the problem. The question doesn't contain full code but it probably should be programming_languages: JSON.parse(programming_languages.value)
